# WordPress jQuery Ajax call fails with no response

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin. There are a number of jQuery Ajax calls, and all of them succeed except for one. This happens to be in an onbeforeunload, which I hope is not the problem, but here's the code:

```
jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var invoiceData = {
        action: 'update_invoice_data',
        invoice_mode: jQuery('#invoice_mode').val()
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"post", 
        url:ajaxurl,
        data:invoiceData,
        error:function(request, textstatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('invoice data pass failed');
            console.log(request);
            console.log(textstatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success:function(result, status, xhr) {
            console.log('invoice data passed');
        },
    });
});
```

(There's more data being passed in the invoiceData variable, but even when I remove everything but the `action='update_invoice_data'` it still fails.)

`textstatus` is simply "error" and `errorThrown` is an empty string. In a header file elsewhere I have:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_invoice_data', 'update_invoice_data');
```

and then the function `update_invoice_data` is elsewhere. There are other `add_action` lines for other functions in the same header which work fine, and other functions in the same file `update_invoice_data` is found that work perfectly.

So my questions are:

1. Is it not legal to do an Ajax call in an onunload function? If so, is there a way around this?
2. If it is legal, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> This happens to be in an onbeforeunload, which I hope is not the problem

That is exactly the problem. The request is being aborted before it finishes. Make it synchronous to solve this problem.

```
async: false
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I knew it was something simple! :)